# How to fetch API as soon as page is loaded in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Whenever I visit a page it should automatically fetch the API

```js
import React from 'react'

const Component = () => {
  fetch("api url").then((res) => console.log(res))
  return (
    <div>comp</div>
  )
}

export default Component
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is very simple using react hook use effect please learn basics of useffect hook on react docs or any youtube tutorial and as for the answer

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react'

const comp = () => {
useEffect(() => {
    fetch("api url").then((res)=>console.log(res))
}, [])


  return (
    <div>comp</div>
  )
}

export default comp
```

here empty dependency means every time page loads only once

Answer (score 2):

use the [useEffect](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html) for this.
The `useEffect` method will execute the passed callback on the mount of the component and on every time one of the dependency array parameters is changed. therefore:

```
const Comp = () => {

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch("api url").then((res)=>console.log(res))
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>comp</div>
  )
}
```

Will make the callback to fire only once (because the empty dependency array) on the component mount.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the useEffect Hook in your principal component like app.js

```
import React, {useEffect} from 'react'


  useEffect(() => {

    fetch("api url").then((res)=>console.log(res))

  }, []);
```

Be careful, this manipulation can consume a lot of resources (a lot of data to fetch etc.)
Thery

Answer (score 0):

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'

const Comp = () => {

const [ data, setData ] = useState([]);

const getData = async () => {
    const res = await fetch("api url");
    const data = await res.json();
    setData(data)
}  

useEffect(()=>{ getData() },[]);

  return (
    <>
    <div>comp</div>
    // dispaly your data here from data state 
    </>
  )
}

export default Comp;
```

Answer (score 0):

Fetch and use data with useState

```
const initialValue = {};

const comp = () => {

 const [data, setData] = useState(initialValue);

 useEffect(() => {

   let ignore = false;
 
   const fetchData = async () => {
         const res = fetch("api url");
         if (ignore) { return; }
         setData(res.json())

         return () => {
            ignore = true;
         }
   }

 , [])


  return (
    <div>comp {data.prop}</div>
  )
}
```

More on [working with state](https://beta.reactjs.org/learn/updating-objects-in-state)
More about [useEffect life cycle](https://beta.reactjs.org/learn/lifecycle-of-reactive-effects)

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use the `API` function like this, it will be called continuously, you need to use [useEffect](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html) hook, when your component reloads `useEffect` will be called, and you can learn about the useEffect dependency [here](https://devtrium.com/posts/dependency-arrays),

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'

const comp = () => {

  const [data, setData] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch("api url").then((res)=> {
      console.log(res)
      setData(res)
    } )
  }, [])


  return (
    // use data state to show the data here
    <div>comp</div>
  )
}

export default comp;
```